# Permanently Reorder tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs

I have some tabs on a page and I want to let a user reorder them, permanently. I am confident I can manipulate the DOM with jQuery enough to reorder them. So my question is, after they have been reordered in the DOM by jQuery how can I get the "hard code" to write to an html file? They are simple tabs in li tags.

```
    <div id="menu">
        <ul id="navMenu">
            <li id="home"><a href="#home" rel="ajax">Home</a></li>
            <li id="privacy"><a href="#privacy" rel="ajax">Privacy</a></li>
            <li id="contact"><a href="#contact" rel="ajax">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

More info: these are loaded from an external "common" html file on multiple pages and I am wanting an admin to be able to add and reorder tabs without having to edit html. I think I want to get the code and pass it to a php file to place/replace in an html file.

Thank you very much,
Todd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If users were able to update files on your server using jQuery/javascript we would all be in big trouble.

This is a huge security risk, because users have full access to client side languages like javascript.  You will need to look at using a server side technology to do this (.NET, PHP etc.)

Comment: That is why I mentioned 'admin'. it is not users it would be one user and it would not be jQuery writing to a file...that is "almost" impossible. I did mention i would pass the data to a php file.

Comment: Oh yeah...will use php to help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't seem feasible using jQuery for sure.

Comment: is it feasible to get the altered html?